# How to do infinite scrolling with flask? (htmx or other methods)

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask, htmx

this is the code that gets post information. ive seen a few things on stackoverflow but none of them really address a core example of infinite scrolling with htmx.

```
                    {% for post in  get_feed_posts(session['username'])  %}
                      {% if post[7] != "off" %}
              
                          {% from 'macros.html' import post_block %}
                          {{ post_block(post) }}
                      {%endif%}
                    
                    {%endfor%}
            
                    </div>
```

update: this wont run the test route

```
DATA = [{"name":"Neil"},{"name":"Corie"}]

def get_data(page=0, pagesize=1):
  print(DATA[pagesize * page: pagesize*page + pagesize])
  return DATA[pagesize * page: pagesize*page + pagesize]

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def test():
  data = get_data(page=request.args.get("page", 0, type=int))
  return render_template("test.html", data=data)
```

-- html

```
<tr hx-get="/test/?page=0"
 hx-trigger="revealed"
 hx-swap="afterend">
 <td>Agent Smith</td>
 <td>void29@null.org</td>
 <td>55F49448C0</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: im sure this post will get flagged and get me blocked from posting questions bc thats how stockoverflow goes.

Comment: Infinite scrolling is achieved by having JavaScript hook in to where a page is scrolled, fetching more content when needed. Flask is just one of many possible mechanisms for initially serving up the page of HTML/CSS, and responding to requests for more content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at https://htmx.org/examples/infinite-scroll/ , you'll see that it sends GET requests to the server with a `page=n` query parameter, when the user scrolls down the page, so your server should return a new "page" of html data

on your flask server then:

```
@app.get("/some-route")
def some_route():
  data = get_data(page=request.args.get("page", 0, type=int))
  return render_template("my-template.html", data=data)
```

where your `get_data()` function returns different data, depending on the page number

this is usually done using SQL Alchemy. Here's an example: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination

but you could also just use a list like:

```
DATA = [{"name":"Neil"},{"name":"Corie"}, ....]

def get_data(page=0, pagesize=20):
  return DATA[pagesize * page: pagesize*page + pagesize]
```

Comment: i understand the python, i copied and pasted the htmx example but it isnt changing the URL or working at all. what should the htmx code be?